# Using react-select-plus with redux saga

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux-saga, react-select

i'm using react-select-plus and redux saga for handling async options. My component is defined like this

```
<Select
              id="portf"
              options={opts}
              value={portfolioValue}
              onChange={value => portfolioSelector(value, mobileNavCollapsed)}
              placeholder="Select Portfolio"
              onInputChange={value =>
                searchPortfolioHandler(value)}
            />
```

When i enter a letter a service is being called and my state is updated successfully. My issue is that my dropdown list is not refreshed with the new values of my state. I've tried isLoading but it didn't work. Do you have any ideas why is this happening? I'm saying again that my state is updated correctly. I just can see the list with the updated values of my state.
Also in the documentation is saying that to load async options externally use the isLoading={true} but it didn't work either

Answer (score -1):

I think you can you Select.Async which means you need to provide loadOptions props which is of functions type and uses two params, one is input and other is callback.

```
loadOptions={(input, callback) => { setTimeout(() => {
            callback(null, {
              options: your options from state,
              complete: true,
            });
          }, 500); }
```